# UITabBarController does not fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I'm developing an app for ios 7 in Xcode 5 using storyboards where the user uses a push segue to push over to a UITabBarController with 2 UIViewControllers "in it". [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwsE7.jpg) a cropped screenshot over the ViewControllers.

I've got this code in my UITabBarController:

```
#import "ViewTVTabBarController.h"
#import "MyManager.h"



@interface ViewTVTabBarController ()

@end

@implementation ViewTVTabBarController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

// Set the BarTintcolor to red and text colors to white
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];

// Set the NavigationItem Title
self.navigationItem.title = [[MyManager sharedManager] selectedTV];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)actionBarButton:(id)sender {
// Offer options for this TV; options like delete, edit, etc
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

And 2 other "normal" UIViewControllers as the 2 tabs. The title does not get set and a NSLog would not fire.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks!
Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as for the question

> What am I doing wrong?

I think maybe the answer is design. Try to use a `UIToolBar` or `UISegmentedControl` in a `UIViewController` to replace the `UITabBarController` which will be pushed in. Or four tabs in one `UITabBarController`

Comment: The 2 UITabBarControllers need to be seperated on a different page, but why doesn't this design work? Are there any unimplemented methods that I've forgotten? @dopcn

Comment: @Erik When a navigationController which is a childviewcontroller of a tabBarController push in a new viewcontroller, the tabBarController's tabBar will not be removed. So if the new viewcontroller happen to be another tabBarController maybe the new tabBar is just under the top tabBarController's tabBar

Comment: @Erik Or you can try assign the property of UIViewController `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to YES

Comment: I'll play with these solutions and see what works out. For now I changed the ViewController to a normal UIViewController - which actually worked better. Thanks though! ;)